# Проблема со Slick Slider. Слайдер на заднем фоне смещается вниз

Tags: html, css, jquery, slider, slider-slick.js

Я верстаю сайт test.sidorov-n.ru

На нём использую slick slider, а именно Slider Syncing.
Первый слайдер расположил абсолютно и использую для смены заднего фона, а второй слайдер служит ориентиром для первого (они листаются одновременно).

Первые два-три круга листания проходят нормально, но потом картинки первого слайдера пропадают (остается только первая). Как показывает инспектор кода они уезжают вниз, но я не пойму почему.

Помогите разобраться, из-за чего это и как можно исправить?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ты лично правил код слайдера или все делал как в документации?

Comment: jQuery тот же что и в примере документации, только в основном слайдере не по 3 а по одному слайду показывается